# Error 0xc0000185 when booting up to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-error-reporting

In my desktop computer, I had Windows 10 installed for sometime, and then I stopped using my computer for around 4 months and then when I tried to boot up my computer it couldn't start, It gives me an error which is `0xc0000185` and it asks me to repair the computer.

The first thing that I did is to install Ubuntu (because I was gonna dual boot Linux and Windows anyway) in order to completely erase the Windows 10 and install a fresh one. After I made a partition for Windows 10 with the Linux tool Gparted, I installed Windows 10 and the same error displayed.

Here is the image but it's in French unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: I did a quick search for "NLS data is missing", and found [quite a few hits from Microsoft sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=nls+data+is+missing+site:answers.microsoft.com). Looks like at least a repair installation is required, if not a complete clean reinstallation. Hope you find something helpful there.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a repair of the windows installation. It looks like when you created the second partition it corrupted part of the windows boot loader. A quick search of the error code 0xc0000185 brought me to this [page](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-error-code-0xc0000185-4691254), which provides a fair explanation of the error code, and multiple solutions to correct the error. You'll most likely need to create a windows boot disk to reference to for the missing files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so It took me a while to figure it out, and simply I had a problem with my HDD. I don't why but it stoped working for some reason (tho it's not an old HDD)